# The digits 3, 4. 5, and 6 are used to form a four digit code. No repeated digits are allowed. How many codes are possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not exactly sure how to solve this specific problem, but I think I would need to come up with 2 or more equations then solve them together... can't come up with equations though. Can I get some help?

Comment: Since all 4 digits are used in the code, the answer is just $4!$

Comment: This is a straightforward application of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Alternately phrased (*though I insist that you should learn the answer via rule of product first*), this is a straightforward application of one of the many uses of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).  Pick what the first digit in the code is.  You have four options.  Pick what the second digit in the code is.  Since you can't have repeated digits, you have only three options.  Continue and then multiply the number of options for each step to get the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No equations are needed. Let's construct the number of codes:

We have $4$ numbers at our disposal. Let's take a number and make it our first digit. There are $\color{blue}{4}$ ways to choose this first number.

Now we choose our second digit. We can't repeat numbers, so we have $3$ numbers left and therefore  $\color{blue}{3}$ ways to choose the second number.

Then we choose our third digit. We can't repeat numbers, so we have $2$ numbers left and therefore  $\color{blue}{2}$ ways to choose the second number.

And now we only have one number left, and so we have $\color{blue}{1}$ way to choose the last number.

So in total we have $\color{blue}{4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 24}$ ways$^{[1]}$ to create such a code.

In general, the number of ways that we can order $n$ objects (such that no object can be used twice) is $$n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \cdots \times 1 = \color{blue}{n!}$$

---

$[1]$ We multiply because if there are $a$ ways to do stage 1 and $b$ ways to do stage 2, the number of ways that stage 1 and 2 can be done is $a \times b$. Likewise, for the $4$ stages we have here, we multiply the the possibility of each stage, giving $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$. This is known as the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: Would it be possible to apply the permutation formula? $n!/(n-r)!$

Comment: @MatinNawabi Absolutely! In terms of permutations (with $_nP_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$), we want to order $r=4$ elements from a set of $n=4$ elements, which means we need $_4P_4 = \frac{4!}{(4-4)!} = \frac{4!}{0!} = 4!$ .

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no repeats, you can think of the first digit having $4$ possibilities. And because you've used that digit already, the next one has $3$ possibilities. And this continues all the way to the end. So your answer is $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$ (the $1$ is there for visuals. You can exclude it and have the same product) which is just $4!$

Answer (score 1):

First, we draw four boxes.  In the first box, there are 4 possible numbers.  In the second box, there are only 3 choices since numbers cannot be repeated.  Repeating this process, we have $4\times3\times2\times1=24$.